# How do I GROUP BY for only one column, while still being able to sort by and select other columns?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a sheet holding raw data that I would like to filter and sort in another sheet.

**Raw data sheet**
[image: Raw data]

The goal of the sheet is:

- Show only the highest `Rank` per `Name` at `Level` 12 or below
- Sort the results from highest to lowest `Damage`

I show and sort all items with a `Level` of 12 or below using `ORDER BY`:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(RAW!2:1000, "select A,B,D where C<=12 and A<>'' order by D desc"))`

**Sorted by Damage**
[image: Sorted]

But this still shows too many entries. I can filter the entries using `MAX()` and `GROUP BY`:

`=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(RAW!2:1000, "select A,max(B) where C<=12 and A<>'' group by A label max(B) ''"))`

**Filtered to only show highest rank**
[image: Grouped]

However, I cannot sort by `DAMAGE` or else I get this error:

```
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: 
COL_IN_ORDER_MUST_BE_IN_SELECT: `D`
```

And attempting to add that column to the `SELECT` clause gives this error:

```
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: 
ADD_COL_TO_GROUP_BY_OR_AGG: D
```

The error means that I cannot include fields that are not either aggregate formulas (like `MAX`) or are not a part of the `GROUP BY` (which `DAMAGE` is not).

My goal is this:

**Filtered to only show highest rank *and* sorted by damage**
[image: Goal]

**How would I go about querying the first sheet to end up with the above sheet?**

---

Here is the actual sheet. Please feel free to fork if you'd like to test an solution.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XG3eTSc-8eYRh-6ekq_2BjZgleUVCz3v45PLozXe8Xo/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you work from your query (arrayformula is not needed)

=QUERY(Raw!2:500, "select A,B,D where C<=12 and A<>'' order by D desc")

You can filter the query results to get your desired output:

```
=FILTER(A2:C,MMULT((A2:A=TRANSPOSE(A2:A))*(B2:B<TRANSPOSE(B2:B)),SIGN(ROW(B2:B)))=0)
```

I have not had success combining the two.

Comment: This seems to get the job done! Now, I'm just trying to understand how it works before accepting it. Thank you for this.

Comment: MMULT is finding the highest value in B of each unique value in A. The '*' is and ('+' would be or). Filter, unlike query keeps column C. Sign changes True/False to a number 1/0.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a trivial answer, but might help to clarify your requirements. In the case of your test data where max(damage) is in the same row as max(rank), you can just put

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(Raw!2:1000, "select A,max(B),max(D) where C<=12 and A<>'' group by A order by max(D) desc label max(B) '', max(D) ''"))
```

If what you want is to sort in general by 'the value of damage that corresponds to the highest rank' then the answer is more complicated!

Comment: While this answer is technically correct for the case given, my goal was to select the rows based on `Level`, `Rank`, and `Name`, and then also return all associated cells. This does answer the actual question, but not the spirit of the question. 